# Inserting data into multiple tables simultaneously using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have read multiple answers around the site but is still confused about a part of it.

To start with ,I have 2 tables **labor_details** and **labor_contact** both of them related using a column labor_id which is primary and auto_incremented.

Now , my plan is to provide a php script to enter data in these tables simultaneously with same labor_id .

One method which i found to work **is mysql_insert_id().**

But wanted to confirm is- will this method work as expected when multiple users will be entering data simultaneously?

Case 1: 
At time 0 ,
User 1 entering Data{insert into labor_details , mysql_insert_id() , insert into labor_contact}
User 2 also entering data.{insert into labor_details , mysql_insert_id() , insert into labor_contact}

Will both of them get same ID when they call mysql_insert_id() or a different one.

Comment: You can test it with the `sleep()` function after the insert using two browser windows simultaneously.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks will try it asap.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id() always return the last inserted row, so if there is two user session then it will definitely return the inserted row id in your case labor_id which is auto increment, will return different for different users.

Comment: Ok. So is my assumption correct  that no matter how many users hit the server simultaneously each will get a different ID ?